# How do I kill background processes / jobs started by a bash script after it finishes executing?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

So I want to start a docker image, then a Django back-end and finally an angular front-end, let them run as long as I need to do tests/develop and then kill them when I'm done. To do this I first tried starting them all in a script and have them run in a background, and have a second script do `kill %n` for both processes. This doesn't work because the background processes are in another context, so the second script cannot reference them.

Then I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Exit Angular, Django and kill docker_img
function clean_up()
{
    echo "Exiting..."
    kill %2 
    kill %1 
    docker stop docker_img
    reset
    exit
}

# Trigger cleanup on CTRL + C
trap clean_up SIGINT

# Start docker database
docker start docker_img

# Start django backend
cd ~/Projects/DjangoBackend
source venv/bin/activate
python src/manage.py runserver &
sleep 3
echo 'Done starting django, starting angular'
sleep 1

# Start angular front end
cd ~/Projects/AngularFront
npm start &
```

However, after `npm start &` runs, the trap stops working, so it effectively becomes useless. I'm guessing it could be because once my script is done running the trap is no longer active, but I don't know how to fix this. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to kill a process in unix/linux, one way of doing it is you can record their PID in a file using ps -ef command.
And then use kill -9  to kill the process.

Example:

```
$ ps -ef | grep <process_name> | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' > pid.txt
$ kill -9 `cat pid.txt`
```

- ps -ef command will give all the running processes, using grep and process name, you can get PID of the particular process
- awk is used to extract only PID from above command
- kill -9  will forcefully kill the process

Comment: the problem with this is that I need to identify each process spawned by django and node, which isn't ideal or very straightforward. If there is no other solution I'll use this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to have been pretty easy, all I had to do was add `wait` to the end of the script, which allows the script to wait until the processes are done executing. Since two of the processes are servers, they don't stop unless prompted, so it'll just wait until SIGINT is received, at that point it'll run the `clean_up` function and exit gracefully.

Additionally, one could use the same trap but with the `EXIT` trigger instead of `SIGINT` to clean up when the script exits on it's own due to the processes closing.